# Alamofire Validate Json Results with multiple Urls

Tags: json, swift, api, youtube, alamofire

I use youtube api and I run out of Quota.

I want to change the URL **(https://example.com/get)** with another URLS in a list  if Json return error until I get a successful Json results.

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/get").validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("Validation Successful")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let urls = ["https://example.com/get","https://example.com/get","https://example.com/get"]
var current = 0
func callAgain(){
    let url = urls[current]
    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful ",url)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            current += 1
            if current < urls.count {
               callAgain()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Khan, in case Successful, how can I return the successful URL??

Comment: Thanks again, but I think there is error in the ( counter += 1) it should be (current)

Comment: also, I want to return the value of the url in  case Successful to be the function (callAgain) return

Comment: search for completions callback in swift

Comment: Thanks so much, I will search for sure, but if you can help me edit the code it will be appreciated :)

Comment: any help regarding updating the code to return the url in case of Successful be the function (callAgain) return pleasssssssssssss